# Reading a float value from an external adress

Tags: c#, readprocessmemory

i am trying to get a float value from an external adress. 
To do this, i am using this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Reader
{
    class Scanner
    {
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll",SetLeastError=true)]
        static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, UInt32 nSize, ref UInt32 lpNumberOfBytesRead);

    unsafe public static string[] getCharValues()
    {
        try
        {
            Process[] pr = Process.GetProcessesByName("Prozess.exe");
            Process process = pr[0];
            uint baseAdress = (uint)process.MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32();
            uint o = 0;
            byte[] ret = new byte[10];
            if(!ReadProcessMemory(process.Handle, (IntPtr)(process.MainModule.BaseAddress+0x156CC38), ret, (UInt32)ret.Length, ref o))
                return new string[] {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().TosTring()};
            return new string[] { BitConverter.ToSingle(ret, 0).ToString() };
        }
        catch(IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Prozess ist vermutlich nicht geöffnet");
            return new string[] {""};
        }
    }
}
}
```

The returned string array is written down in a text box, but it is always 0. it should actually be about 8000 (that's the output of cheat engine)
What am i doing wrong?

Error code is 299

Comment: "but it is always 0." You're ignoring errors. Change that and update the code here.

Comment: "IndexOutOfRangeException/vermutlich" Don't do such vague error handling. Check the length of pr before accessing it so that you don't crash. Right now this overly generous catch will swallow a lot of errors, not just the one you are looking for. Post the full exception here should there be any.

Comment: Does the `ReadProcessMemory` return true of false? If it returns false (error), you need to know why. In your `DllImport` attribute set [SetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.setlasterror(v=vs.110).aspx) to true, and then use [GetLastWin32Error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the error code

Comment: @YacoubMassad Updated the code. Error is 299

Comment: Look for this error code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @YacoubMassad Already seen it, but what am i supposed to do now?

Comment: How do you know that you are reading from a valid location?

Comment: a float has a size of 4. Why are you reading 10 bytes? try to change the array size from 10 to 4.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this quickly but this is the idea:

```
public float ReadFloat(InPtr address, HANDLE pHandle)
{

    byte[] memory = new byte[4];

    if (ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, address, memory, (UIntPtr)4, IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        float value = BitConverter.ToSingle(memory, 0);
        return value;
    }
    return 0.0f;
}
```

If it's double precision, use 8 bytes for the array size, make sure you read 8 bytes and use Bitconverter.ToDouble(), and change float to double